# When compiling fmtlib include file in Linux with g++ compiler getting an error of class is private and cannot be accessed from outside

Tags: c++, c++11, formatting, c++17, g++

I am using #include <fmt/ranges.h> to format std::array in my C++ application

```
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<short unsigned int, 3> arr = {1, 2, 3};
    fmt::print("{}", arr);
}
```

It is properly compiling in windows and macos but failing in linux with g++ compiler with the below errors:

../externals/fmtlib/fmt/ranges.h:49:29: error: all member functions in class 'fmt::v10::detail::is_std_string_like' are private [-Werror=ctor-dtor-privacy]
template  class is_std_string_like {

../externals/fmtlib/fmt/ranges.h:65:29: error: all member functions in class 'fmt::v10::detail::is_map' are private [-Werror=ctor-dtor-privacy]

template  class is_map {

../externals/fmtlib/fmt/ranges.h:49:29: error: all member functions in class 'fmt::v10::detail::is_std_string_like' are private [-Werror=ctor-dtor-privacy]
template  class is_std_string_like {

../externals/fmtlib/fmt/ranges.h:65:29: error: all member functions in class 'fmt::v10::detail::is_map' are private [-Werror=ctor-dtor-privacy]

template  class is_map {

As of the time of writing, MSVC and Clang are the only 2 compilers supporting the header. Is it not supported with g++

It seems that MSVC and Clang are the only 2 compilers supporting this header <fmt/ranges.h>. And g++ is not supporting this header.

Please help me.

Comment: g++ is correct that all member functions *are* private. There are other public members though. If you don't want warnings for such classes, you have to turn it off.

Comment: Thank you @BoP. You mean to say only option is to turn of those warnings. Is there any other option to make use of these headers without turning off the warning?

Comment: I haven't used fmt with g++, so cannot tell what else would happen. But generally compilers warn about odd things that *might* be a problem - like having no callable functions in a class. In this case it is not an error, but an unusual design choice. So you would have to tell the compiler that in this case it is ok.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, the program compiles with no warnings or errors.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, Thank you. I am using the gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) . With this gcc version, when compiling, i am getting the above mentioned errors.

Comment: All member functions in fmt::v10::detail::is_std_string_like are **not** private as we can plainly [see](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/10.0.0/include/fmt/ranges.h#L49). We also don't get this error with [this gcc version](https://godbolt.org/z/PYWGcjqrG). Something is broken at your side.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are opting into `-Werror=ctor-dtor-privacy` which rejects valid C++ code and the solution is to remove this flag from your build flags, at least when compiling `fmt/ranges.h`.

Comment: *rejects valid C++ code* That's what warnings are *for*---to scream at technically valid but suspicious code. The code in fmt/ranges.h as found in the repo is not suspicious however. There are public member functions in it, and the problem cannot be reproduced by others. So turning the warning off would amount to sweeping the dirt under the rug.